# Why is my Kivy windows Executable not running?

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, kivy, kivy-language

I have made a kivy app and packaged it as an executable file but for some reason the executable is only opening for a split second then closing without showing anything. I am sure none of my code is flawed as it works when ran in my text editor, what can I do to fix this issue?

Spec file-

```
from kivy_deps import sdl2, glew

# -*- mode: python ; coding: utf-8 -*-

block_cipher = None


a = Analysis(['C:\\Users\\Admin\\Assignment\\Info_Tech_Assignment.py'],
             pathex=['C:\\Users\\Admin\\Desktop\\Tech'],
             binaries=[],
             datas=[],
             hiddenimports=[],
             hookspath=[],
             runtime_hooks=[],
             excludes=[],
             win_no_prefer_redirects=False,
             win_private_assemblies=False,
             cipher=block_cipher,
             noarchive=False)
pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data,
             cipher=block_cipher)
exe = EXE(pyz,
          a.scripts,
          [],
          exclude_binaries=True,
          name='Info_Tech',
          debug=False,
          bootloader_ignore_signals=False,
          strip=False,
          upx=True,
          console=True )
coll = COLLECT(exe, Tree('C:\\Users\\Admin\\Assignment\\'),
               a.binaries,
               a.zipfiles,
               a.datas,
               *[Tree(p) for p in (sdl2.dep_bins + glew.dep_bins)],
               strip=False,
               upx=True,
               upx_exclude=[],
               name='Info_Tech')
```

Python code -

```
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen, ScreenManager
from kivy.properties import StringProperty, ObjectProperty
import webbrowser
from kivy.uix.image import Image
from kivy.core.window import Window
import keyboard



class Login(Screen):
    def validate(self):
        user = self.ids.input_1
        pwd = self.ids.input_pwd
        info = self.ids.info

        uname = user.text
        passw = pwd.text   

        
        if uname == '' or passw == '':
            info.text = '[color=#FF0000]Username or password needed[/color]'
        else:
            if uname == 'Savant' and passw == 'root':
                self.parent.current = 'contentpage'
            else:
                    info.text = '[color=#FF0000]Username or password is invalid[/color]'
    pass

class TableOfContents(Screen):
    pass

class WorldWideWeb(Screen):
    def web(self):
        webbrowser.open("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tim_Berners-Lee")
    pass

class HypertextMarkupLanguage(Screen):
    pass

class HypertextTransferProtocol(Screen):
    pass

class Hyperlinks(Screen):
    pass

class WebServer(Screen):
    pass

class Webpage(Screen):
    pass

class FileTransferProtocol(Screen):
    pass

class WebBrowser(Screen):
    pass

class UniformResourceLocator(Screen):
    pass

class UploadandDownload(Screen):
    pass

class Email(Screen):
    pass

class Pictures(Screen):
    pass

class References(Screen):
    pass

class WindowManager(ScreenManager):
    data_dir = App().user_data_dir
    
    pass

kv = Builder.load_file("rtech.kv")

class info(App):
    def build(self):
        return kv

if __name__ == "__main__":
    Window.maximize()
    info().run()

keyboard.wait('esc')
```

Comment: run it from the command prompt and then you will easily be able to see the actual error message ... likely its missing some fonts or other data files

Comment: @JoranBeasley Thanks for the advice, I googled the exact error and I found my problem was that I was running the wrong exe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue, it was because I was running the `build` folder executable not the `dist` folder executable, aparently it is a common error people make.